# Measuring Pressure Difference From MPX10DP sensor using Arduino

Tags: arduino, air-pressure

I'm trying to measure differential pressure of air from MPX10DP sensor using Arduino. This sensor has a very low voltage output that is about 35 mV, so Arduino UNO cannot read it directly. Thus, I implemented the sensor with an amplifier circuit I saw in internet that was used with MPX2010DP sensor then I connected it to Arduino. The problem is that results are always constant regardless of the code I'm using or the Air flow input I'm changing. I even tried to measure the voltage output using MATLAB software, but results were also voltage constant line with time. The schematic diagram and the datasheet of the sensor are included here [MPX10DP Datasheet](https://datasheet.ciiva.com/26929/mpx10dp-26929337.pdf). Please help me to know if the mistake is in the sensor, circuit, or code?
**Note: The amplifier uses here is instrumentation amplifier of type AD620**
[image: BLOCK DIAGRAM]

Comment: can you draw this in schematic form for people not familiar with the AD620 pinout? Thanks

Comment: Searching for mpx2010+amplifier+adc gives circuit based on operational amplifier that should work.
You may check your software by applying some voltage to ADC input and see whether reading will change. AD620 also requires buffered reference voltage source to set zero pressure difference to be read as middle of ADC range, this is necessary to measure both signs of pressure difference.

Comment: Thank you for your response, may I know what kind of voltage I can apply to ADC to test the software?